# Mysql insert multiple unique rows

Tags: php, mysql, hash, transactions

Wondering if this procedure can be accomplish without having any data error. Using PHP7 and MySQL innoDB. This is still in theory stage and if you can give good input and recommendation before the project starts would be a tremendous help.

The case will be that there will be multiple transactions and there could be multiple transactions happening at the same time even in microseconds.
The `transaction` table will have a hashed column where the value of hash is the hashed of all the information of that transaction + salt + the previous hash value entry (if exist).

The process will be:

1. PHP will receive transaction order (user info, amount and etc)
2. PHP get the value of the previous transaction hash (if exist)
3. If there is no transaction exist (first transaction), PHP will hash the entire transaction information (sha256), Hx0 and MySQL will create it's first entry with the hash value of Hx0
4. If there is already a transaction before, PHP will take the previous hash value (Hx0) and hash it along with the entire current transaction info (sha256), Hx1{Hx0} and MySQL will create the new entry in the database
5. This process repeats all the way between PHP and MySQL, Hxn+1{Hxn}

My concern is, if there could be a possibility of several transaction using the same hash value of the previous transaction if those transaction occurs at the same time?

For example, latest Tx hashed value is abcd. If 5 new transaction goes in at the same time in microsecond, will those 5 use that same latest Tx hashed value abcd? The result i'm trying to achieve is that it will be in order and use the latest hashed value properly.

[edited]
Let me try to explain more clearly.

1. First transaction will have the value of hash `hash(info + timestamp)` = "acbd"
2. Second transaction will have the value of `hash(info + timestamp + "abcd")` = "cdfg"
3. Third transaction will have the value of `hash(info + timestamp + "cdfg")` = "hijk"

My concern is that if 3 transactions enter at the same time in microseconds or nanoseconds after that third transaction, will the new 3 transactions be like as follows? (fourth transaction is still hashing with the previous hash, while the fifth transaction and sixth transaction is also hashing using the same previous hash, before fourth transaction even manage to complete and update to database) :

1. Fourth transaction `hash(info + timestamp + "hijk")` = "12sd"
2. Fifth transaction `hash(info + timestamp + "hijk")` = "x3sd"
3. Sixth transaction `hash(info + timestamp + "hijk")` = "n76h"

I would expect and hope that my results to be:

1. Fourth transaction `hash(info + timestamp + "hijk")` = "12sd"
2. Fifth transaction `hash(info + timestamp + "12sd")` = "mn34"
3. Sixth transaction `hash(info + timestamp + "mn34")` = "09lk"

Plan B is (what do you think?):

1. Create two tables. One (table A) to receive all transaction without hashing, and another (table B) to hash each transaction in table A one by one.
2. Table A will insert all entries regardless if it's in nano second simultaneously.
3. Table B will just happily go through Table A and hash each entry one by one which also not affected by the simultaneous transactions and having the hash value properly in order.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your hashing function uses as argument. Let me teach you a mathematical beauty behind hashing functions:

### No collision and robustness

Hash functions are meant to not create **collisions** and to be **robust**.

- What is a **collision**? Consider `f` as hashing function and `x` and `y` two different strings. A collision would happen if there would exist two different strings `x` and `y` such that `f(x) = f(y)`. Obviously this is **very not good**. Therefore hashing functions are designed so that they create no collisions.
- What is **robustness**? Unlike in previous case, let now `x` and `y` be two equal strings. We want the hashing function to return same value no matter when we run it on same string, therefore a hashing function is robust, if for `x = y`, it is also `f(x) = f(y)`.

Now that we know that, we must ask ourselves what we want to pass to hashing function. Obviously something that is distinct from user to user, e.g. password, username, e-mail, a combination of those. Also we can add something to it, a *salt*, like date, just to make it more complex but there is really no necessity.

### Your case

So basically what you want to worry about is only what data are you going to be hashing, which is username, amount, etc. Since the PHP script will run separately for each transaction and since data you will be hashing will be different (amount, time, etc. might be the same, but username will be different), there is no need to worry about collision.

Comment: I understand the beauty of the hashing and i understand that sha256 probability to collide is as the probability of 1 in the amount of atom in the universe. My concern is that could the 5 new simultaneous transaction be using the same previous transaction hash value in it's new hash? Since the hash value is for example = sha256(previous hash [if exist] + amount + user name + timestamp + salt)

Comment: No. You start with 0 transactions. No hash value. First transaction comes, there will be no previous "hash value" plus each request to server will run each own instance of php script, thus won't be able to see what others' value is. Also you use username in hashing, which will result in each hash value of separate transaction to be unique.

Comment: i'm not really worried about it's uniqueness, i'm worried if it's not in order and use the same hash value of the previous transaction. i've updated my question content. hopefully that can show a bit of clarity. apologise if my explanations were not that concise.

Comment: Now that is completely up to randomness. It is definitely possible that transactions come in so quick that they would actually use the same hash value... There is a problem with this thinking tho: a friend asked me a question some time ago: "if two bullets from two different players hit the enemy in exact same time (in call of duty game), who would get a kill?" Well the server CANNOT receive two requests at THE SAME TIME, it might get down to processor ticks, but there is still a tiny difference. This means that no, two transactions will not use the same hash value... UNLESS! ...

Comment: Each request is getting processed in own thread and you do not save the new hash value quickly enough. Meaning for example that thread1 calculates new hash value, but before it writes it to database, the other thread reads hash value from database. Since the first thread didnt put the new one in database, the second thread will extract the old one. So if you want to use new hash value every time you want to make sure that if you are doing multithreading in any way (workers for example) that the new value has been saved. There is no problem in using the same value, I guess it's theoretical Q ^^